# Sidebar not displayed. How to tackle this?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have add sidebar to category. But sidebar not displayed in old articles.

if i am adding a new article and by adding this article to category then sidebar will displayed in article page.

While sidebar not displayed in old articles.

Please Help

Comment: I got lost on the second line. Please provide more detail with relevant screenshots

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/VWybyeVlG8

Comment: Here you can check http://screencast.com/t/H2PZQourGK

Comment: Cqan you clarify your question please, sorry it is really doesn't read :/